# Use of comma before "wer"

Tags: sentence-structure

I like to learn German from the instructions given in class and one such instruction was presented below:

> Wenn du Informationen darüber hinzufügen möchtest, wer die Handlung ausführt, kannst du *von (+ Dativ)* verwenden.

Now, I understand this sentence means roughly:

> When you want to add information about who did the action, you can use *von + dative*.

But the part

> Wenn du Informationen darüber hinzufügen möchtest, wer die Handlung ausführt

bothers me as I can't sense why there is the need for a comma between "möchtest" and "wer".

Is there a reason for this? What kind of clause is being presented in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler example:

> Ich möchte Informationen darüber, wer die Handlung ausführt.

*wer die Handlung ausführt* is a subordinate clause (*Nebensatz*, or more precisely, a *Relativsatz*). A *Nebensatz* always requires a comma in German. But even Germans often make the mistake of omitting the comma, although the rule is quite simple.

Actually, the rule is only this simple for finite subordinate clauses. An infinitive clause is more complicated, because the comma rules have been relaxed with the orthography reform of 1996. But the in the case of *um zu* + object + infinitive, the comma is also mandatory:

> Ich benötige Informationen, um die Handlung auszuführen.

Comment: Fabulous. So this applies to all subordinate clauses?

Comment: All subordinate clauses need commas in German. However, there are short *zu-infinitive expressions* which have been considered to be subordinate clauses in the past but not any more.

Answer (score 0):

See it like this:
the sentence has three parts

- you want to add
- who did the action
- you can use

So there are 3 parts with subject and verb each. In German you separate those parts of a sentence with comma if there is no other separator like the word *und* in between them.